# 3 way bulb only works 3 way for a few hours

Tags: electrical

I put a 3 way bulb in a lamp. It worked fine.  Next day, only 1 level worked. I tried it in another lamp, only 1 level.  I tried this with 2 different 3 way bulbs.  Could the lamp be bad?

Comment: Is it LED or incandescent?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.